# Xamarin: why need the BusinessEntityBase class

Tags: xamarin

I want to learn Xamarin and i took a look at a sample project called 'Tasky'
But i don't understand why theres a BusinessEntityBase class...
A task also needs it's ID to be PK and incremented so why doesn't it implement
the BusinessEntityBase class instead of the IBusinessEntity interface?

[image]

```
public class Task : IBusinessEntity
{
    public Task ()
    {
    }

    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    // new property
    public bool Done { get; set; }
}

  public abstract class BusinessEntityBase : IBusinessEntity 
{
    public BusinessEntityBase ()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Database ID.
    /// </summary>
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

    public interface IBusinessEntity 
    {
    int ID { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

IBusinessEntity interface is just that - an interface, the properties of which (in this case, ID) would be a part of every business entity. Read up on the use of Interfaces in C# to get a better understanding of why this is done.

Another example would be:
Lets say you have an employee management application which contains three different kinds of users - Manager, Developer, Tester. You have a class for each of these.

It is very likely that all three of them contain an ID field, a first name and a last name.

Instead of adding the same properties to each of their classes, you create an interface called IEmployee, which has three fields - ID, FirstName and LastName and get each of the three classes to implement it.

Functionally, implementing the properties on an interface and adding them manually has the same effect on the class. Although, having an interface connecting all three of them, you now have a more abstract way to access your data (For example, to count the number of employees, you could check the count of IEmployee objects, rather than counting all three separate and then adding the numbers up).

TL;DR Doing it this way is not mandatory. In this scenario you could simply have a BusinessEntity class that has an ID field. It is simply a good practice and makes your applications easy/possible to maintain when they grow.